# usar ion-select dinamicamente

Tags: html, ionic, sqlite, apache-cordova, ionic3

Coloquei como opções no ion-select, Zona sul, norte, centro e Oeste. Eu quero quando clicar em alguma opção, mostrar apenas as informações daquela zona pegando as informações do banco de dados. No momento eu só tenho o select mesmo.

```
<ion-item no-lines class="setaselect">
  <ion-label stacked color="carioca" >REGIÕES</ion-label>
  <ion-select>
      <ion-option value="opt1"></ion-option>
      <ion-option value="opt2">Zona Oeste</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="opt3">Zona Norte</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="opt4">Zona Sul</ion-option>

  </ion-select>
```

DB.ts

```
getRegiao(pregiao: string){
return new Promise<Regiao[]>((resolve, reject) => { 

  let sql = "select * from tb_regiao" + pregiao;
  console.log(sql);          
  this.executeQuery(sql).then(data => {
    let regioes = [];
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      let regiao: Regiao = { nom_regiao: row[0]}
      regioes.push(regiao);
    });
    resolve();

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

});


}
```

e minha função  ts.

```
 selecionaregiao(pregiao: string) {
this.db.getRegiao(pregiao)
        .then(data => this.regioes = data)
        .catch(error => console.log('Something want wrong!'));
 }
```

Mas eu não sei exatamente como faço isso, nem consigo pesquisar exatamente o que eu quero. Como ainda estou aprendendo, resolvi pedir essa informação aqui :D
Se alguém souber como faço isso, ou algum tutorial, eu realmente não estou sabendo pesquisar como fazer isso.

Comment: Você já sabe como pegar a informação do banco ou precisa disto também ?

Comment: eu ja uso o banco de dados sqlite.. Tenho segment buttons no meu codigo, e clicando neles ja recebo as informações do banco. Só quero agora quando selecionar a região, busque apenas as informações do banco dessa região. Já criei a tabela e as colunas no banco. Só preciso agora usar no select :D

Comment: Postei como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Faz uma função que busca os dados e faz o seguinte no seu componente: 
Cria um NgModel para o seu select e chama uma função ao mudar o dado.

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="suaFuncao()" [(ngModel)]="regiao">
      <ion-option value="opt1"></ion-option>
      <ion-option value="opt2">Zona Oeste</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="opt3">Zona Norte</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="opt4">Zona Sul</ion-option>

  </ion-select>
```

No typescript faz:

```
regiao: any; //Se tiver um tipo específico coloca ele

suaFuncao(){
    //Chama a função para buscar do banco de dados e passa this.regiao como parâmetro.
}
```

Comment: Estou recebendo o seguinte erro "core.js:1449 ERROR Error: no such table: tb_regiaoundefined
    at Database.webpackJsonp.318.Database.handleError "  sabe me dizer oq pode ser?  Vou deixar no meu post meu db e minha função, se puder me diga o que pode estar errado. Ainda sou novo com Ionic e banco de dados tem sido algo um pouco complicado.

Comment: ao que parece a sua variável preregiao está undefined.